# On web, how do I control the visibility icon that automatically appears on a focused TextFormField that has an obscureText property set to true?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Here's my code for the password field:

```
TextFormField(
  obscureText: isObscure,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    suffix: TextButton(
      child: isPasswordObscure
          ? Text(
            'Show', 
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          )
          : Text(
            'Hide',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() { isObscure = !isObscure; });
      },
    ),
  ),
)
```

If I run it, the password field would look like this:
[image]

If you review my code, I only specified a text button and not an icon as the suffix. The visibility icon was added by <s>Flutter</s> Edge and when I click on it, it only changes its icon and does not unobscure or obscure the text field.

[image]

What I want to know is how do I change or remove the icon? And maybe also give it a callback so it knows what to do when I click on it.

The problem doesn't exist on mobile, only on <s>browsers</s> desktop Edge.

**Edit:**
I tried setting `suffix` and `suffixIcon` to null but the visibility icon is still showing.

**Update:** I've discovered that the problem only exists on MS Edge.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
// the magic function
void fixEdgePasswordRevealButton(FocusNode passwordFocusNode) {
  passwordFocusNode.unfocus();
  Future.microtask(() {
    passwordFocusNode.requestFocus();
    js.context.callMethod("fixPasswordCss", []);
  });
}

// widget code
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (_) async {
                fixEdgePasswordRevealButton(passwordFocusNode);
              },
              focusNode: passwordFocusNode,
              obscureText: true,

// end of index.html
    window.fixPasswordCss = () => {
      let style = document.createElement('style');
      style.innerHTML = '::-ms-reveal { display: none; }';
      document.head.appendChild(style);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Also posted on the relevant [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83695#issuecomment-1083537482).

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to turn off the visibility icon set onPressed: () {},
also if you want to remove the visibility icon form overview wrap it with opacity widget

Opacity(
opacity: 0.0,
child: textButton(),

Comment: Hi, please read again my question. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code sample to include the visibility option for the textField. by including a variable `_isObscured` in a stateful widget. we have implemented it with the auto obscure after 2 second delay.

```
 Center(child: TextField(
        obscureText: _isObscured,
        decoration : InputDecoration(
        suffix:InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                    setState(() => this._isObscured = 
                    !this._isObscured);
                    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
                      setState(() => this._isObscured = 
                      !this._isObscured);

                    });
                },
                child: Icon( Icons.visibility),
            ),
         ),
      ), 
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Hi, please read again my question. Thanks :D

Comment: @BlazeT. are you using any libraries to generate form.

Comment: Nope, I'm not. Are you able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: nope. We can't I could get only normal textfield

Comment: Resolved it. It shows only on Microsoft Edge and not on Google Chrome. Don't know about other browsers though.